# Perl exceptions instead of return values

Tags: perl, exception

In some perl scripts I find myself writing things like:

```
open(...) or die $!;
print ... or die $!;
```

etc.

I'd like to avoid repeating myself saying `or die ...` at the end of every possible exception.

Is there a way to force functions like `open()` etc to throw an exception when they error, not just a false return value? Then I could catch all possible exceptions in one go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It exists a module that makes those instructions die on an error, it's called `autodie`. Add it at the beginning of your script.

```
use autodie;

## It dies.
open my $fh, '<', 'nonfile.txt';
```